# Android - How to check if variable exists when reading response data from server

Tags: java, android, variables, retrofit2

How to check if variable exists when reading response data from server?

```
if(response.result.vendor == null){
    cardVendor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else {
    cardVendor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    getVendor(response.result.vendor);
}
```

my retrofit request :

```
@GET("ac_transactions/{id}")
Call<TransactionDetailResponse> getTransaction(@Path("id") String id);
```

my class loader :

```
public class TransactionLoader extends RequestBuilder{
    public void load(String id, final TransactionDetailListener listener){
        Call<TransactionDetailResponse> call = request.getTransaction(id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<TransactionDetailResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TransactionDetailResponse> call, Response<TransactionDetailResponse> response) {
                listener.onResponse(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TransactionDetailResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                listener.onFailure(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is the reponse i get from server when the vendor variable is not exist :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Post Ac_transactions Successfully",
    "result": {
        "__v": 0,
        "updatedAt": "2018-02-21T08:06:38.811Z",
        "createdAt": "2018-02-21T08:06:38.811Z",
        "category": "perawatan ac",
        "sub_category": "cuci ac",
        "type": "dinding",
        "notes": "panas cah",
        "unit": 2,
        "building_type": "rumah",
        "date": "2018-02-19T00:00:00.000Z",
        "time": "21.00",
        "ladder": "yes",
        "address": "banguntapan",
        "coordinates": [
            -7.743286,
            110.381376
        ],
        "amount": 150000,
        "customer": "5a8d288e8c68eb61f361a011",
        "_id": "5a8d288e8c68eb61f361a012",
        "status": "new order",
        "hidden": false
    }
}
```

and the error when variable name is not exist :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse a JSON ? If this is the case use a [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Comment: FYI i use retrofit 2 lib

Comment: I know, it's in your tags. You have to be more specific in your post. Show us the retrofit service and the request url.

Comment: @OmarAflak ok i just update my post

Comment: Your code looks okay. The error indicates that you are using `equals()` method but here you wrote `== null` so the error is from somewhere else. Where are you using `equals()` ?

Comment: @WresniWahyuWidodo where are you using `equals()` method ?

Comment: The problem is when the vendor variable not exist on response like my response above